# How to post information to Eloqua, by calling Eloqua API from a class

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I don't know much about Eloqua or oAuth, I wanted to know How to create a service to connect to Eloqua and call API

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Eloqua oauth is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/GettingStarted/Authentication/authenticate-using-oauth.htm

This is the documentation for the bulk api: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/BulkAPI/bulk-API.htm

You can start by using a rest client (like postman or fiddler) to play with the API.

Is there anything specific you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add a user to Eloqua, Post method. I am not sure which post method to use .

Answer (score 1):

I have to write an answer because my reputation is too low to comment...

**You can not create a user via REST API or Bulk API.** Maybe with SOAP but it's deprecated.

[See all endpoints for users here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/api-Application-1.0-Users.html)

Your question is not clear:

- What do you call a "service" ?
- What do you want to achieve ? And how ?
- Does OAuth is mandatory ?

And finally, with REST API you can not connect and then executes your actions, you have to authenticate you each time you call an endpoint. You are probably aware of this, but this may seems unclear in your question.